# Using two different microphones in Dragon NaturallySpeaking: different user profiles vs. same user profile with different sources

Tags: windows-7, microphone, dragon-naturally-speaking

When using two different microphones in Dragon NaturallySpeaking, in terms of speech recognition accuracy is it better to use two distinct user profiles, or is it OK to use the same user profile with different sources? Both microphones are connected via USB, but are very different: the first one is a [Sennheiser ME 3-EW](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002FOFW52), while the second one is a stenomask ([Sylencer SmartMic SM 100](http://talktech.com/products/stenomask-sylencer/)).

I would prefer to add a new source to my existing profile instead of creating a new user profile as it would allow me to use the same custom commands and vocabulary, but I worry it may decrease the accuracy.

I use Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12.5 Professional with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking.  Are you asking if one is more effective than the other (in which case, why not just test it)?  Are you trying to have two profiles/equipment independently translate and then combine the results to capitalize on different strengths of each?  Are you asking whether you will get better results using a different profile for each microphone (again, why not test it)?

Comment: @fixer1234 It's not possible to combine two different audio sources in Dragon NaturallySpeaking. I'm asking if one yields a higher speech recognition accuracy than the other. I'm looking for experienced users of Dragon or whether Nuance gives any recommendation: it's not something you can test easily.

Comment: @CloseVoter: Speech recognition accuracy is not primarily opinion-based. Please leave a comment to explain your vote.

Answer (score 1):

Using multiple sources for the same profile will NOT degrade accuracy, BUT...

Assuming you are plugging both mics into the same USB sound card then you won't really be able to set them up as separate sources in the same profile. As I see it, you have two options:

1: Use both mics with the same profile, and simply run the mic check each time you switch to get the best volume settings for that dictation session

2: Since you're using Professional you can export/import all of your custom commands and vocabulary and create a second profile for the alternate mic.

A third option would be to get a second, different, USB sound card, such as the SpeechWare MultiMatic which might improve the performance of the Sylencer thanks to the Auto Gain Control, and then you could set it up as a separate source in your existing profile.

See the [Nuance Knowledgebase ID 6276](http://nuance.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/6276/) for more info.

Please update with what you decide to do and how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

From an experienced user (Lunis Orcutt) https://www.knowbrainer.com/forums/forum/messageview.cfm?catid=6&threadid=23439&enterthread=y&STARTPAGE=1 ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20190508053826/https://www.knowbrainer.com/forums/forum/messageview.cfm?catid=6&threadid=23439&enterthread=y&STARTPAGE=1)) :

> Beginning with Dragon 13, Nuance introduced Manage Dictation Sources which you will find under the Profile menu. Rather than maintaining 2 separate profiles, we simply recommend maintaining 2 separate dictation sources for your 2 different types of microphones.